# Do I always need to specify the array shape when reading from shared_memory (Python 3.8)?

Tags: multiprocessing, shared-memory, distributed, python-3.8

I am trying to use shared_memory on a distributed cluster with Python multiprocessing. Each time a worker is created on a new node, I need it to check whether a shared memory block with a particular name already exists and, if not, create it from a subset of a table from an external database. This shared memory block should then be accessible to all future workers on that node.

However, the example in the Python documentation (https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.shared_memory.html) only seems to work when the shape of the array is known in advance:

```
# Attach to the existing shared memory block
existing_shm = shared_memory.SharedMemory(name='psm_21467_46075')
# Note that a.shape is (6,) and a.dtype is np.int64 in this example
c = np.ndarray((6,), dtype=np.int64, buffer=existing_shm.buf)
```

Is there any way to check the shape of an array in a shared_memory block without it being passed to the worker as an argument (my workers cannot communicate with each other)?

Comment: Sometimes it seems like I'm the only person on earth trying to use shared_memory...

Comment: shared memory simply exposes a blob of memory that you can attach a numpy array to because numpy supports the buffer protocol. If you give numpy a blob of 400 bytes what shape do you think it should be? it could be any layout totaling that size.

Comment: I would use something like a message queue to send the name, size, shape, and datatype to connect to shared memory. Short answer to your title: Yes

Comment: Thanks! I don't know how to set up a message queue using Dask. Can you recommend any resources?

Comment: Dask is a very complicated framework, so it may already have mechanisms for what you're talking about. I am only familiar with the builtin `multiprocessing` tools, for which I would just use `multiprocessing.Queue`

Comment: Thanks, if I can't figure it out with Dask, I'll try multiprocessing.